# Codeigniter 3 with SQLite 3: no such table

Tags: php, codeigniter, sqlite, codeigniter-3

I always get the following error in my codeigniter 3 application when I start using a sqlite3 database.

```
SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such table: pages
```

I have read somewhere that this is the case when you have the wrong path to the databse. My database is located in `application/db/pages.sqlite`

This is the config for the sqlite database:

```
$db['pages'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => APPPATH.'db/pages.sqlite',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlite3',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me before

```
'database' => 'sqlite:'.APPPATH.'db/pages.sqlite',
```

Also make sure that folder db is readable by your app.

Comment: Doing this just gives me another error: `Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.` Which I guess makes more sense, but still not really.

I also set the database to `0777` for testing and it doesn't help.

Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check that sqlite3 php module is installed on your web server or not?
This will required to work Codeigniter3 sqlite3 db driver.

If its not working then provide 'dsn' string. This will definitely working.

Answer (score 0):

First thing try to check your php.ini and uncomment this

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
```

and try this

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'sqlite:application/db/pages.sqlite',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```